# Changing a string dynamically for file usage

Tags: java, file

I am trying to figure out how to make a string that I can use to create a file in my java program. I have tried many different ways of doing this, but nothing seems to do what I want.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
String fileExt = ".jpg"
for (int i = 0; i < someNumber; i ++){
     fileExt = i + fileExt;
}
```

I want to output something like:

1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg 
... and so on.

My intention is to use the changed string at every iteration in order to create a new file with it like so : File image = new File (fileExt;

Comment: your intention is still very unclear.

Comment: I am trying to make a string that changes at every iteration. This way I can make a file like so File image = new File (fileExt);

Comment: Throw a `println()` in the loop, and you should be able to figure out what your problem is.

Comment: it still doesn't make sense. what's the file for? for temporary writing or permanent storage? any encoding rules? you need to review your own question after asking to make sure your description can be understood.

Comment: Sorry, to me it makes sense. I didn't think it was important to discuss that as I am focused on trying to generate a string. The reason for the file is not really important.

Comment: What problems are you having with the current approach? You mention the intention of creating a new `File` but your code sample contains nothing related to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what you do, the value of fileExt is going to be the last iteration of the loop. Maybe an array will do the trick?

```
String[] fileExt = new String[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < fileExt.length; i++) {
        fileExt[i] = i + ".jpg";
    }

    // view results
    for (int i = 0; i < fileExt.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(fileExt[i]);
    }

// example
    File image = new File(fileExt[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
String fileExt = ".jpg"
for (int i = 0; i < someNumber; i ++){
     File newfile = new File(i + fileExt);
     files.add(newfile)
}
```

A few things here. filext should be absolute path, or the files will be created in your current directory. Keep file references in List for future use.

Comment: wouldn't that make files as such : 1.jpg, 1.jpg2.jpg, 1.jpg2.jpg3.jpg ?